# Run Same Task multiple times parallel [POWERSHELL]

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, task

i need to run this function multible times parallel.

I need to do it does not have high CPU usage, but takes very long time.

```
$sha256 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
$utf8 = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
function GetNumbersAndHashes {
    param (
        $End
    )
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $End; $i++) {
        $hash = @{}
        
        $GenHash = $sha256.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($i))
        $GenHash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($GenHash).Replace('-', '').tolower()
        
        $hash.Add($i, $GenHash)
        
        Write-Output $hash
            
        Write-Output `n $hash.Keys /  `n 
            
        $hash.Keys >> "C:\Users\user\Desktop\NumbersClear.txt"
        $hash.Values >> "C:\Users\user\Desktop\NumbersHashed.txt"
    }
}
```

I need to get all the numbers from 0 to 10000000000 and wanted to do it with 10.000 Steps or more running at once. But i dont know how to start these "Jobs" and provide the $End variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best code and the result will be unsorted since it returns the values depending on when the job finishes.

```
$Threads = 10000
$maximum = 1000000 
$increase = 10000
$start =  0
$res = $null

$ScriptBlock = {
    param($start, $increase) 
        
        $sha256 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider
        $utf8 = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
        $hash = @{}

        for ($i = $start; $i -lt ($start+$increase); $i++) {
                
        
            $GenHash = $sha256.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($i))
            $GenHash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($GenHash).Replace('-', '').tolower()
        
            $hash = $hash + @([pscustomobject]@{Key=$i;Hash=$GenHash})
        
            
                
        }

        return $hash
  }



while($start -lt $maximum) {

    Write-host $start
    Write-host $maximum
    # Execute the jobs in parallel
    Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $start, $increase
  
    $JobCount = @(Get-Job -State "Running").Count 
  
    While (@(Get-Job -State "Running").Count -gt $Threads) 
    {  
        #Write-Host "Waiting for some jobs to finish, currently $JobCount jobs are running! | Scanned Servers: $ScannedServers of" $servers.Count
        Start-Sleep 1 
    }

    $start += $increase
}



# Wait for all to complete
While (Get-Job -State "Running") { Start-Sleep 5 }


# Display output from all jobs
$res += (Get-Job | Receive-Job -Keep)

#$res 


$res.Key >> C:\temp\NumbersClear.txt
$res.Hash >> C:\temp\NumbersHashed.txt


# Cleanup
Remove-Job *
```